# What is the origin of the idiom of “to stick it to someone”?

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang, phrase-origin

My cursory review so far has only been able to uncover the fact that dictionaries can’t even have a consensus on the exact meaning of it, and they differ substantially in how they define it.

Collins — “to harshly criticize, punish, or retaliate against someone”

Dictionary.com — “[to t]reat someone badly or unfairly”

Idioms.thefreedictionary – “ To intensely confront, punish, or retaliate against someone, perhaps vindictively or with unnecessary severity”

Urban Dictionary — “[to d]emonstrat[e] to the opposition you will not be a pushover[; i]n many cases, this term is associated with a positive cause, such as friendly competition in sports, or political statements or acts against oppressive policies.”

I tend to agree best with the Urban Dictionary definition, but the primary question is the origin.

Is it an implied reference to the male part?